# Conditional Formatting - Highlight certain cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

(Excel 2016)

I would like to figure out how to have a cell highlighted if another cell has data in it, and 2 other cells are blank. In other words, if there is anything populated in column N, if the cell in the same row in columns S and T are blank, it should be highlighted.

What I am trying to accomplish here is when I receive a report from a vendor with a revised ship date (column N), they need to assign a comment and reason code (column S and T), however this doesn't always happen. I'm hoping that when they input something into column N, then the cell in the same row in column S and T lights up, it will help remind them.

I've trying playing around with it and can't quite make it work. Thank in advance, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It should be a simple matter of

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(N1)), ISBLANK(S1), ISBLANK(T1))
```

Comment: That almost worked, but it highlighted N1 when I entered in data. I would like it to highlight S1 and T1 and leave N1 alone. I appreciate the help!

Comment: The only way that could have happened is if you applied the formatting to cell N1.  If you don’t want to format cell N1, then don’t apply formatting to it; apply formatting to the cells you want to format (S1 and T1).  If you can’t get it to work, describe much more clearly what you are doing and what results you are getting.

Comment: Thank you that fixed the problem! I do have one additional question. When I put data into N1, S1 highlights. How do I get both S1 and T1 to highlight until they are filled in? I put the formula into both S1 and T1, but only S1 seems to work.

Comment: Ok so I figured out how to have them both highlighted, my only problem now is when either S or T has data put into it, the other highlight goes away. I would like both S and T to stay highlighted until both fields have data put into them.

Comment: EDIT - Got it figured out, thank you so much!!!

Comment: I’m glad you got it to work. If you feel that my answer was useful to you, [please ‘‘accept’’ it by clicking on the checkmark to the left](/help/someone-answers).